# Linux distro with C/C++ development tools included

Tags: linux

I work at a company that does not allow Internet access to Linux based machines.
However, I need to develop C programs for my job.  (Strange I know...)

Is there a Linux distro with common IDEs and development libraries included in the ISO?  I need GTK development tools as well as Qt.

I need an ISO, or possibly one package I can download on a Windows machine before installing it on Linux.

Obviously downloading dependencies becomes very annoying (and imposible somtimes) without a direct internet connection.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Drill down through http://distrowatch.com. And, welcome to Superuser `:-)`

Comment: what about using a windows machine with a Linux VM?  or Cygwin?

Comment: Sort of related but from almost 4 years ago: http://superuser.com/questions/57127/what-is-the-best-linux-distro-for-development-of-c-c-programs

Comment: While long and painful, you might have some luck with [this offline install method](http://kmandla.wordpress.com/2007/07/24/howto-download-packages-and-dependencies-for-offline-installation/). Or maybe [this](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/) package downloader. If you only need to do it once, or very rarely, it might be easier to just grit your teeth and do it.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from trying to get your company to change their policy (which sounds backwards to me - where do the majority of viruses and DOS attacks come from?), [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/overview.html) or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is probably your best bet. Sure, you could download some ISOs and run Linux natively, but without net access you'll be missing out on software updates, bug fixes, newer versions of libraries/compilers/language runtimes/etc., online help systems, the whole gamut, and it'd be a real PITA to either have two machines side-by-side, one for devel work and one for net access. How do you copy and paste a code fragment from StackOverflow, for example?

I use VMWare Fusion on my Mac to run Linux, and I really like it, but it's a commercial product and does cost money. VirtualBox is the *de facto* standard on Linux, and is free-free (beer-speech) but I'm not sure if it handles 3.x kernels yet - honestly I'm not that familiar with it. [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is an option, but my experience with it a few years back left a lot to be desired - honestly, if you want to run *nix, then run it, don't try to backport parts of it onto Windows.

Good luck!

Comment: Technically, this may violate the 'no Internet access for Linux' policy, but is likely to be a good and viable option for the OP. +1.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm trying to push for that, but I don't think they will allow any internet connected Linux system.  VM or not.

Comment: @DRJTower - just wondering - what exactly is their justification for no Linux net access? Surely any filtering/firewalling/whatever they're doing is OS-neutral?

Comment: Even if you have to turn off network access for the VM, there are still a lot of advantages to running a VM over a dual-boot system, or side-by-side machines, copying/pasting and sharing files being the ones that immediately come to mind...

Comment: This company is very concerned about privacy and does not allow any executables to be downloaded/installed without IT aproval. They have Windows tools to monitor/watch for this. I guess Linux is too open/easy to get around these restrictions. Does'nt make a whole lot of sense to me, but since I'm fairly new here so I'm not going to argue with the IT policies too much.

Comment: @DRJTower well, like I said in my answer, Good luck!